# difference between "will be doing" and "be doing" when use the continuous form for the future

Tags: present-continuous, future-continuous, future-constructions

I am confused about the following description of 'will be -ing' from a grammar book, which says:

> We also use 'will be doing' to talk about complete action in the future.

Here is the example in which the grammar book says "will be -ing" is similar to the present continuous for the future:

> A: If you see Sally, can you ask her to phone me?
>
> B: Sure. I'll be seeing her this evening, so I'll tell her then.

I suppose the sentence "I'll be seeing her this evening" means the speaker has arranged to see her and is doing that this evening. So, can I rewrite the sentence into "I'm seeing her this evening" without meaning change? I wonder whether "will be seeing" and "am seeing" are interchangble in the case. If not, what difference is there between these two continuous forms when they talk about the future?

Comment: Yes, both tenses can be used to refer to arrangements for the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Will" vs "going to" vs present continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/will-vs-going-to-vs-present-continuous)

Comment: The suggested dupe doesn't include anything about future continuous, so I don't see how it can be a dupe

Comment: @KateBunting, Is there any difference between these two forms when talking about arrangements for the future?  I quote the excerpt from my grammar book here, which says "we also use 'will be doing' to talk about complete action in the future. ... 'will be -ing' is similar to the present continuous for the future." I wonder whether they are interchangeable in the example given above.

Comment: I don't see any difference. The future continuous here implies 'In the normal course of events, I expect to see her.'

Comment: @KateBunting, got it, Thank you so much